# Power BI NATURALINNERJOIN override active relationship with USERELATIONSHIP

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have the following tables with 3 relationships (1 active, 2 inactive):

- Table 1 (Relationship: Column 1)
- Table 2 (Relationship: Column 1, Column 2, Column 3)

The active relationship is on Column 1 of Table 1 and Table 2. I join these tables like this:

```
NATURALINNERJOIN(SELECTCOLUMNS('Table 1', "Column 1", 'Table 1'.[Column 1] & ""), SELECTCOLUMNS('Table 2', "Column 1", 'Table 2'.[Column 1] & ""))
```

Works great!

I want to do another `NATURALINNERJOIN` but this time on `'Table 1'.[Column 1]` and `'Table 2'.[Column 2]`. How do I use `USERELATIONSHIP` to override the active relationship and use the inactive ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to override the relationship if you're creating a calculated table. Just specify your desired columns. e.g.

```
Table3 = 
NATURALINNERJOIN(SELECTCOLUMNS('Table1', "Column 1", 'Table1'[Column1] & ""), SELECTCOLUMNS('Table2', "Column 1", 'Table2'[Column3] & ""))
```